# AccessDenied in Orchard CMS 1.4.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I converted one of my solution to Orchard 1.4.1 with proper database.

`Q1: Whenever I run or goto any link by clicking menu item then it always hits to AccountController/AccessDenied method of Orchard.Users. why?`

`Q2: How to resolve this?`

Please help

Comment: @bertrand-le-roy: ya checked error log and a problem occurs for DataPrefix. But after fixing that, now i am getting a problem,

HttpException was unhandled by user code
The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.

and for now, error log is empty

Comment: From what version did you upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios in which this may happen:

1. **You updated from 1.3 (or older) versions to 1.4.1.** If that's the case - check the [1.4 upgrade information.](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-1-4-Release-Notes) *EDIT: Actually this is probably not your case - you would get 404's, not AccessDenied, in this scenario.*
2. **You are using the source code from recent 1.x development branch.** There is a new module in the works that will allow to restrict visibility of certain pages to specific users. If that's the case - go to admin screen and assign Page "View" permissions to Anonymous role.

Comment: After some of fixing, now I get an error `The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.`
and page not found.